# DotNetOpenAuth - Google Apps OpenID login failed, x is not a secure Identifier

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth, google-apps, google-openid

We are testing an OpenID DotNetOpenAuth ASP.Net website on a subdomain named like test.xyz.com, and both http and https are enabled. We also enabled "requireSSL". We are getting this error when we try it with the Google Apps OpenID endpoint:

> Login failed: Sorry. This site only
>   accepts OpenIDs that are
>   HTTPS-secured, but
>   http://xyz.com/openid?id=102043883906843397279
>   is not a secure Identifier.

I'm not sure what we are doing wrong. Maybe I forgot to setup something?

Am I right if I say that http://xyz.com/openid?id=102043883906843397279 is just an ID, not a functionning link?

Carl

Answer (score 0):

We simply disabled requireSSL in DotNetOpenAuth and it now works. Not yet sure of it's use.
Carl